# Rails controller view bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Alright total noob, tried to find out what was happening but I haven't seen this come up with anyone else as far as I could find.

I'm going through a very basic blog tutorial with rails for the second time. made the home controller and the index view for it. all good. Next i made the 'posts' controller with basic classes and then views for index, edit, new, and show.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index

end

def new

end

def create

end

def edit

end

def update

end

def show

end

def destroy

end
end
```

The html for the views in their respective files

```
<h1>New Posts</h1>
<h1>Edit Posts</h1>
<h1>Show Posts</h1>
```

PROBLEM: In the browser when I go to localhost:3000/posts/edit it displays "Show Posts" instead of "Edit Posts". /show also displays "Show Posts". /new works fine and displays "New Posts".

I checked and it looks like localhost:3000/posts/literallyanything will display "Show posts".

I know this is potato level but I thought it was really odd and can't figure out why that would happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a resource route for posts defined in your routing file like this:

```
resources :posts
```

you need to hit

```
localhost:3000/posts/<post id>/edit
```

More docs on routing here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You can always run rake:routes from your terminal to find out what route you need to hit for any given controller action.